# Abrir Fancybox em página específica

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um banner em fancybox que abre em todas as páginas. Porém, quero que abra apenas quando o usuário estiver na Home do site.

Eu estou chamando o javascript abaixo em um arquivo .php que faz a chamada do script em todas as páginas do site.
Então, coloquei apenas no arquivo home.php que serve apenas para a Home do site. Pois, não quero que o Fancybox não apareça em outras páginas. Somente na Home.

Porém, o fancybox não está sendo chamado.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $.fancybox.open({
           src : '/assets/images/banner-aviso.png',
           type : 'image'
         });
     });
</script>
<a class="hidden-link pop-up" href="/assets/images/banner-aviso.png">&nbsp;</a>
```

No console, aparece o seguinte aviso:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined   at (index):36 (anonymous)
>   @ (index):36"

Que no caso seria o `"$(document).ready(function() {"`

Será que o JS não está sendo chamado na página Home?
Como eu faria uma verificação em PHP para ver qual a URL da página?

Comment: O jQuery não está sendo carregado.

Comment: Como eu faria uma verificação em PHP para ver a URL?

Comment: Mas e aí, como eu faria para ele abrir o Fancybox após a verificação?

Comment: Sim. Existem dois arquivos: home.php e index.php - A index.php passa pro todas as páginas.

Comment: @FelipeStoker a URL tem o formato `http://site.com/home` ou `http://site.com/home.php` ou `http://site.com/?pag=home`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar em qual página está usando `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` e verificando com `strpos()` se a string `/home` está na URL atual.

É importante também verificar se o jQuery está sendo carregado na página. O ideal é carregá-lo no `<head>`, antes de todos os *plugins*. A estrutura básica seria assim:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/home')){
    // está na home. Aqui você carrega os scripts que quiser apenas na home
?>
<script src="caminho_do_fancybox/fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
       src : '/assets/images/banner-aviso.png',
       type : 'image'
    });
});
</script>
<a class="hidden-link pop-up" href="/assets/images/banner-aviso.png">&nbsp;</a>
<?php
}
?>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: E como eu colocaria aquele script, no caso?

Comment: Assim? https://jsfiddle.net/kdo7ksaq/

Comment: @FelipeStoker Veja que coloquei o 'REQUEST_URI' entre aspas simples.

Comment: Na verdade a URL é /home. Acho que posso colocar isso, ao invés de "home.php"?

Comment: @FelipeStoker sim, coloque "/home" no lugar de "home.php"...

Comment: Estranho que fiz tudo isso. E não está chamando o **Fancybox**.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Carregue script do Fancybox no mesmo lugar. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @FelipeStoker Veja se está retornando erro no console.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar `parse_url` para checar o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

**Nota 1:** o erro:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):36 (anonymous) @ (index):36"

Indica que o jQuery não foi carregado na sua página, é necessário colocar ele antes do script que deseja executar, algo como:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="pasta/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="pasta/fancybox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <?php if (<condição>): ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fancybox.open({
           src : '/assets/images/banner-aviso.png',
           type : 'image'
        });
    });
    </script>
    <a class="hidden-link pop-up" href="/assets/images/banner-aviso.png">&nbsp;</a>

    <?php endif; ?>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

**Nota 2:** o `REQUEST_URI` tem que ter os apóstrofos (aspas-simples), pois se fizer `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` **o PHP** vai procurar primeiro uma constante chamada `REQUEST_URI`, que não existe, então vai emitir um **notice** assim:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI'

O `assumed 'REQUEST_URI'` indica que o PHP por não achar a constante fez um cast para string, no entanto note que apesar de `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` funcionar, mas se calhar de algum script adicional gerar a constante `REQUEST_URI` com algum \valor, então isto vai falhar com certeza.

Note também que `strpos()` pode retornar `0` ou `false`, no caso do script do @DVD não, ainda sim se você estiver acessando uma pagina com o nome parecido `foobarhome.php` o `strpos` também vai entrar no `IF`, então o ideal para evitar problemas é usar o `parse_url` ou então usar `preg_match`, segue exemplos:

### Usando parse_url

O `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)` vai extrair somente o `path`, se estiver na home o valor `/home`

```
<?php if (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) === '/home'): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $.fancybox.open({
           src : '/assets/images/banner-aviso.png',
           type : 'image'
         });
     });
</script>
<a class="hidden-link pop-up" href="/assets/images/banner-aviso.png">&nbsp;</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Se a home que se refere é a index.php, então faça assim:

```
<?php if (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) === '/'): ?>
...
```

Se for um range de páginas, pode usar um array:

> Nota: o `ltrim` tira a barra do começo

```
<?php
$pathAtual = ltrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/');

$permitidos = array( 'home', 'contato', 'admin/foo' ); //Adicione as páginas permitidas aqui
?>

<?php if (in_array($pathAtual, $permitidos)): ?>
...
```

### Com preg_match (regex)

Neste caso usei [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (expressões regulares), com ele você pode criar um range de páginas dentro da regex, por exemplo esta regex vai checar se é a home ou a index `#/(index|home)$#`, exemplo:

```
<?php if (preg_match('#/(index|home)$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $.fancybox.open({
           src : '/assets/images/banner-aviso.png',
           type : 'image'
         });
     });
</script>
<a class="hidden-link pop-up" href="/assets/images/banner-aviso.png">&nbsp;</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```